# How to use Amelia package to get a best time series model in R

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I'm trying to handle the missing data from a data frame use multiple imputations, professor advice me to use Amelia package. And I can build the time series model, but when I try to use lapply function to repeatedly run the time series model in each dataset, I got an error on the function in lapply.

My data frame have three variables, date, pm25, pm10. I can built an AR model for pm25.
And the imputation code is:

```
imp <- amelia(Exetertibble, m=50, ts = "date")
```

So I can get 50 imputations, and the time series model would like this:

```
model1 <- arima(imp$imputations$imp1$pm25, order = c(1,0,0))
```

Then I try to use lapply function:

```
extractcoefs <- lapply(imp$imputations, coef(model1))
```

There is an error, it said that the coef(model)is not a function or character or symbol.

My aim is to combine the 50 imputations and get the best result of coefficient of the time series model, I don't know how to write a correct function in there.

I also tried:

```
extractcoefs <- lapply(imp$imputations, coef(arima(order=c(1,0,0))))
```

and:

```
extractcoefs <- lapply(imp$imputations, arima(order=c(1,0,0)$coef))
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea, what you are trying to do.

Look at this example for lapply:

```
x <- list(a = 1:10, beta = exp(-3:3), logic = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
# compute the list mean for each list element
lapply(x, mean)
```

So you give `lapply` a list und apply a function on each of the list elements. In this case the function is `mean()`.
So for this example you will get the mean for `a`, `beta` and `logic`.

You are using `lapply` on `imp$imputations`.
You got `imp$imputations` from your call to  the `amelia()` function. Which gives you  an instance of S3 class "amelia". This instances includes several objects, one of these is a list `imp`, which has as list elements all the imputed datasets (in your case 50).

So using `lapply(imp$imputations, coef(model1))` will apply the function in the second part on all imputed datasets. The only problem is, your second part isn't really a function. Also you can't apply `coef` on the imputed datasets. You must apply `coef()` on a model object, because it returns the model coefficients form the model.

I guess you want to do the following:

1. Generate your m=50 imputed datasets
2. Build a arima model for each dataset
3. Get the coefficients for each of this model

You could just use a for loop through the m=50 datasets for this.

Take this as an example:

```
data(africa)
imp <- amelia(x = africa, cs = "country", ts = "year", logs = "gdp_pc", m = 5)

for (i in 1:length(imp$imputations)) 
{
  model <- arima(imp$imputations[[i]]$gdp_pc)
  coe <- coef(model)
  print(coe)
}
```

This would give you 50 results of `coef`. (for the different arima models build on the different m=50 imputed datasets)

Comment: Thank you so much! I run it successfully. I have imputed 50 results of the coef, but how can I choose the best one from it? I intend to follow an example use data(africa): `lm.amelia.out <- lapply(imp_amelia$imputations, function(i) lm(gdp_pc ~ civlib + trade,
data = i))`   `coefs.amelia <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lm.amelia.out, function(i) coef(summary(i))[,1]))`
`ses.amelia <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lm.amelia.out, function(i) coef(summary(i))[,2]))`
`mi.meld(coefs.amelia, ses.amelia)`
It finally use mi.meld to get the best coefficient of the model, how can I do like that?

Comment: What do you mean with the "best" model ? Each coefficients you got are the best ones for the datasets you fitted them on - with the model you chose. (coefficients are different, because the m datasets the model got fitted on are different). You fitted the same model on each dataset - e.g. a arima(order=c(1,0,0)) model. Which would be an AR(1) model. A call to arima() does no model selection, it just fits the model you chose to the data. If you use e.g. auto.arima() from the forecast package, this does also model selection.

Comment: But would you mind explaining what your overall goal is and how do you think the m=50 imputations are useful for this...?

Comment: I would like to build a time series model, but the dataset has missing data. And I have to use the multiple imputation method to handle the missing data. I chose m = 50 because my teacher advices that, he thinks that the more the m is, the better result we get. I originally used m=5. So now I get 50 coefficients and 50 models, I don't know which one should I choose to do other analysis like predict or make some plots. Sorry I'm new to R. Really thank you for your help!